# The "While locked" or "When device is locked" menu is missing in settings

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Using Lenovo A5000. Recently Android 5.0.2 update arrived. After updating I was asked about the notifications at lock screens. I would like to change my choice but there is no menu "While locked" or "When device is locked" in Sounds and notofocations. Have anybody seen that? And how can I fix it? The lock screen is unlocked with pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Security settings and select "screen lock". Create a lock (even if you have one already). After confirming the lock, you will be asked to change how your lock screen notifications are displayed. Change according to your liking.